# Change Plot3D, etc., axes orientation and position?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

On paper or a blackboard, mathematicians (as opposed to engineers, physicists, etc.) typically draw 3D plots is with:

1. axes origin is at (0, 0, 0) and axes are drawn emanating from there;
2. the positive *y*-axis points due east, the positive *z*-axis points due north, and the positive *x*-axis pointing southwest (as if pointing forward, out of the paper); and
3. the positive ends of these axes have arrowheads (just plain 2D arrowheads, not conical or similar quasi-3D objects.

In other words, the way that's shown in this image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space#/media/File:Coord_planes_color.svg:

[image: Wikipedia drawing of 3D axes.]

What is the best way to arrange this for `Plot3D` and the family of related functions (`ParametricPlot3D`, `SphericalPlot3D`, etc.)?

I'm aware of using options `Boxed -> False`, `AxesOrigin -> {0,0,0}`, `Axes -> True`, which accomplishes (1). But how best accomplish (2) and (3)?

More specifically:

- For (3), is there some better way than the awkward method of using `Show` to combine the `Plot3D` with a `Graphics3D` consisting of three commands such as `Arrow[{{0,0,0}, {1,0,0}}]`?
- For (2), is there some better way than effecting a geometric transformation on each geometric object created?

Comment: For (2), you can use `ViewPoint` (which can be used in `Plot3D`).

Comment: You *should* be able to achieve (2) using `ViewMatrix` - during my quick testing however, I have unfortunately failed to do so... For (3), I think you'll have to draw the arrows yourself. You might want to use ``Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]`` to get the tick marks and manually draw them as well. (That might yield a cleaner result)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled across it and thought I'd post this in case it helps someone in the future. I use something like this:

```
ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}][{1, -2, 0.85}]
```

Comment: That does *not* seem to make the y-axis horizontal on the page, e.g., in `Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 16] &) /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thick,
 Boxed -> False,
 ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}][{1, -5, 0.85}]]`

Comment: Ah yes, so sorry I read the question too hastily. That said, I believe ViewMatrix can accomplish this. I’ll give it a go and post back if I can make it work, although I’m guessing you’ve already found a suitable solution.